# What is the most efficient way to RTRIM a STRING without using RTRIM in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In a single-select-statement, I have the need to `RTRIM` a string in a SQL Server 2005 environment.

What is, in your opinion, the most efficient technique to achieve this?

Examples:

```
'ALPHA    ' ==> 'ALPHA' (the blanks at the end are removed)
' BETA  ' ==> ' BETA'  (the blank in first position remains, the two blanks at the end are removed)
' GAMMA' ==> ' GAMMA'  (the blank in first position remains)
```

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

EDIT: I am not authorized to use `RTRIM`!!

Comment: Just use `rtrim()`

Comment: `select rtrim(col1) from YourTable`

Comment: I am not authorized to use RTRIM.  Sorry for haven't specified it in time!

Comment: That would have been good to know.  I'm a little confused why you can't use `RTRIM`, however, unless it's some sort of challenge.

Comment: Try this Declare @str Varchar(50) = ' GAMMA'

;With Cte As(
Select
   Data = Substring(@str,Number,1)        
 From  master.dbo.spt_values
 where Number Between 1 And Len(@str)
 And Type='P' )
 
 Select Data = Replace(Bar,'&#x20;',' ')
 From 
 (Select 
 Cast(Data As Varchar(Max))
 From Cte
 For Xml Path(''))Foo(Bar)

Comment: If needed put that into a function. and pass the value. It will do the RTrim but not LTrim.Test your program and let me know in case of any issues

Comment: `Reverse( LTrim( Reverse( Foo ) ) )` is not the _most efficient_ implementation of `RTrim( Foo )`.

Comment: @HABO - that assumes they're allowed to use `LTrim` or `Reverse`

Comment: Answer just accepted, thank you again! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Declare @str Varchar(50) = '      GAMMA    ' 
;With Cte As
( 
    Select Data = Substring(@str,Number,1) 
    From master.dbo.spt_values 
    where Number Between 1 And Len(@str) And Type='P' 
) 
Select Data = Replace(Bar,'&#x20;',' ') 
From (Select Cast(Data As Varchar(Max)) From Cte For Xml Path(''))Foo(Bar)
```

**Result**

```
Data
      GAMMA
```

Comment: I was waiting for your public posting of your code ;-)  Answer just accepted, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

One way as `LEN(CHAR_FIELD_OR_VAR)` ignores trailing spaces;

```
left(fld, len(fld))
```

or

```
select left(fld, (len(fld + '.')-1)-patindex('%[^ ]%', reverse(fld))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select rtrim(ltrim(col)) from....
```

That will trim both sides of the column

Comment: Not authorized to use LTRIM and RTRIM.

Comment: Something else must be wrong. Normal trim functions are always possible when you have select access.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in the title:

```
SELECT Columm1
, RTRIM(Column1) as Column1Trimmed
FROM Table1
```

RTRIM is the most efficient method of Right TRIMming.

Without RTRIM:

```
select '*          *'
, REPLACE('*          *',' ','')
```

Comment: Not authorized to use LTRIM and RTRIM